# Split each arraylist/list element into tuples of ints and strings

Tags: regex, scala, split, tuples

I parsed sql insert statements into list of values like the following:

```
List(6606 'TIMI YURO' 'HURT' 0)
List(6607 'TIMI YURO' 'WHAT*S A MATTER BABY' 0)
List(6608 'TIMI YURO' 'MAKE THE WORLD GO AWAY' 0)
List(6609 'HELMUT ZACHARIAS' 'WHEN THE WHITE LILACS BLOOM AGAIN' 0)
List(6610 'JOHN *THE COOL GHOUL* ZACHERLE' 'DINNER WITH DRAC' 0)
List(6611 'MICHAEL ZAGER BAND' 'LET*S ALL CHANT' 0)
List(6612 'ZAGER AND EVANS' 'IN THE YEAR 2525 (EXORDIUM AND TERMINUS)' 1)
List(6613 'RICKY ZAHND / BLUEJEANERS' 'NUTTIN* FOR CHRISTMAS' 0)
List(6614 'WARREN ZEVON' 'WEREWOLVES OF LONDON' 0)
List(6615 'ZOMBIES' 'SHE*S NOT THERE' 0)
```

Now, for each list, I want to split ints and strings into a tuple of 4.I am not good at regex. If I do `split(" ")`, then in some cases where I have a complex string with spaces such as `WHEN THE WHITE LILACS BLOOM AGAIN` which I want to maintain as a single string tuple value, it does not work. I tried `.map( recordID => ( recordID(0), recordID(1), recordID(2), recordID(3) ) )` but I will get out of bound exception. I would appreciate if anyone can help.

**Update**:
The following is the original sql statements. It is very long but I'm just posting a sample. I want to read from a file each value into tuples of 4 (int, string, string, int):

```
insert into songlist (id, artist, title, numone) values (6606, 'TIMI YURO', 'HURT', 0);
insert into songlist (id, artist, title, numone) values (6607, 'TIMI YURO', 'WHAT*S A MATTER BABY', 0);
insert into songlist (id, artist, title, numone) values (6608, 'TIMI YURO', 'MAKE THE WORLD GO AWAY', 0);
insert into songlist (id, artist, title, numone) values (6609, 'HELMUT ZACHARIAS', 'WHEN THE WHITE LILACS BLOOM AGAIN', 0);
insert into songlist (id, artist, title, numone) values (6610, 'JOHN *THE COOL GHOUL* ZACHERLE', 'DINNER WITH DRAC', 0);
insert into songlist (id, artist, title, numone) values (6611, 'MICHAEL ZAGER BAND', 'LET*S ALL CHANT', 0);
insert into songlist (id, artist, title, numone) values (6612, 'ZAGER AND EVANS', 'IN THE YEAR 2525 (EXORDIUM AND TERMINUS)', 1);
insert into songlist (id, artist, title, numone) values (6613, 'RICKY ZAHND / BLUEJEANERS', 'NUTTIN* FOR CHRISTMAS', 0);
insert into songlist (id, artist, title, numone) values (6614, 'WARREN ZEVON', 'WEREWOLVES OF LONDON', 0);
insert into songlist (id, artist, title, numone) values (6615, 'ZOMBIES', 'SHE*S NOT THERE', 0);
```

Comment: what is the expected outputs ?

Comment: (6609 'HELMUT ZACHARIAS' 'WHEN THE WHITE LILACS BLOOM AGAIN' 0).map( recordID => ( recordID(0), recordID(1), recordID(2), recordID(3) ) ) where id 0 is int, id 1 is string, id 2 is string, id 3 is int.

Comment: I want to get tuples of 4.

Comment: Each `List` is a mix of `Int` and `String`. That means that the compiler doesn't know what type each individual element is. That's a bad situation. It would be much easier to create the desired tuples if the data didn't get mixed like this beforehand.

Comment: @jwvh see my update might help you understand my problem.

Comment: @YCF_L please see my update.

Comment: you cannot have space sepated List in scala as `List(6609 'HELMUT ZACHARIAS' 'WHEN THE WHITE LILACS BLOOM AGAIN' 0)` . If you have List as `val list = List(6609, "HELMUT ZACHARIAS", "WHEN THE WHITE LILACS BLOOM AGAIN", 0)` then you can create Tuple4 as `val tuple4 = Tuple4(list(0),list(1),list(2),list(3))`

Comment: @KaliaDona; I presume that the data types are known when they are read from the file. Or maybe everything is read as a `String` and converted thereafter. Either way, **don't** mix types in a `List`. You'll lose the type information that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the lines of the input and do something like this

```
val line = "insert into songlist (id, artist, title, numone) values (6606, 'TIMI YURO', 'HURT', 0);"
val parseInsertRegex = raw".*values \((\d+), '(.*)', '(.*)', (\d+)\);".r
line match {
    case parseInsertRegex(id, artist, title, numone) => (id.toInt, artist, title, numone == "1")
}
```

This returns me

```
res0: (Int, String, String, Boolean) = (6606,TIMI YURO,HURT,false)
```